# OpenGL: Zero active uniforms

Tags: c++, pointers, opengl, glsl

I'm referring to the OpenGL SuperBible. I use their framework to create an own program. I wanted to do something with an Interface Block (specifically a Uniform Block). If I call

```
glGetActiveUniformsiv(program, 1, uniformIndices, GL_UNIFORM_OFFSET, uniformOffsets);
```

I get an error, namely `GL_INVALID_VALUE`.
But if I call the same function with a 0 instead of a 1, it doesn't make that error. I assumed then, that I have no active uniforms. I should have 3 of them, however.
How do I activate them? Here's my shader:

```
#version 450 core                        
layout (location = 0) in vec4 position;  
layout (location = 1) in vec4 color;     
out vec4 vs_color;                       
uniform TransformBlock {                
    mat4 translation;                    
    mat4 rotation;                        
    mat4 projection_matrix;             
};                                      
void main(void)                          
{                                        
    mat4 mvp = projection_matrix * translation * rotation ;    
    gl_Position = mvp * position;  
vs_color = color;                   
}
```

Here is some code from the startup method:

```
    static const GLchar* uniformNames[3] = {
        "TransformBlock.translation",
        "TransformBlock.rotation",
        "TransformBlock.projection_matrix",
    };
    GLuint uniformIndices[3];
    glUseProgram(program);

    glGetUniformIndices(program, 3, uniformNames, uniformIndices);

    GLint uniformOffsets[3];
    GLint matrixStrides[3];
    glGetActiveUniformsiv(program, 3, uniformIndices, GL_UNIFORM_OFFSET, uniformOffsets);
    glGetActiveUniformsiv(program, 3, uniformIndices, GL_UNIFORM_MATRIX_STRIDE, matrixStrides);

    unsigned char* buffer1 = (unsigned char*)malloc(4096);

//fill buffer1 in a for-loop

    GLuint block_index = glGetUniformBlockIndex(program, "TransformBlock");
    glUniformBlockBinding(program, block_index, 0);
    glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, (GLuint)buffer1);
    free(buffer1);
```

However, as a consequence of the function returning `GL_INVALID_VALUE` there's an error with the calls:

```
*((float *)(buffer1 + offset)) = ...
```

and the whole program interrupts. Without adding the `offset`, I don't get an error here, so I think the second error depends on the first error.

Comment: I think you should have made a new question for a completely new issue. At first glance, this now looks like your vertex attrib pointer setup is wrong.

Comment: I just thought I'd have to comment the whole code snippets again. That would be sort of redundant to comment the same snippets again. Or is it a complete new problem and has nothing to do with the problem now? You know, this whole code worked before I changed the setup to a uniform block-based structure, so to speak. So I don't know whether the problem is the vertex attrib. It could of course be, I'm not an expert. If the question is completely new, I'll of course start a new thread.

Comment: looks like a completely new problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it goes wrong at `glGetUniformIndices`, because you prefixed your uniform names with `TransformBlock`. You don't use that to access the uniforms with that prefix in the GLSL code, either. If you wanted that, you'd had to set an *instance name* for the uniform block, the *block name* is not relevant for accessing / naming the uniforms at all. It is only used for matching interfaces if you link together multiple shaders accessing the same interface block.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think it helped quite a bit. Now I have made an "edit" at my question. Can you help me with that one too? You can find the edit at the bottom of the question.

Comment: I think you need to bind UBO in your render function before call to glDrawArrays.